# Similar pairs in a tree

Tags: algorithm, search, tree

This is a problem from a Hackerrank contest:

You are given a tree where each node is labeled from 1, 2, …, n. How many similar pairs(S) are there in this tree?

A pair (A,B) is a similar pair iff

- node A is the ancestor of node B
- abs(A - B) <= T.

Input format:
The first line of the input contains two integers n and T. This is followed by n-1 lines each containing two integers si and ei where node si is a parent to node ei.

Output format:
Output a single integer which denotes the number of similar pairs in the tree

Constraints:

```
1 <= n <= 100000  
0 <= T <= n  
1 <= si, ei <= n.
```

It is also guaranteed there are no cycles, but the tree does not have to be a binary tree.

Sample Input:

```
5 2
3 2
3 1
1 4
1 5
```

Sample Output:

```
4
```

Explanation:
The similar pairs are: (3, 2) (3, 1) (3, 4) (3, 5)

Now, the brute force approach solves about half of the test cases, but for the other half it is simply to slow. I tried to extent the algo by storing the interval of the subtree of a node and thus being able to eliminate some branching, but overall just a couple of more points.

Any ideas on how to solve this search efficiently?

Comment: What was what you're considering "the brute force approach"? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, how about this solution?

Traverse the tree in pre-order (like DFS), and maintain a multiset `S` for querying.

On entering node `x`, just add `x` into `S`. On leaving node `x` (by leaving, in this context, I mean a time just after all children of `x` is visited), remove `x` from `S`. By doing this, for all time during the tree traversal, you have **all the ancestors of `x`** in `S`.

Let's now compute similar pairs whose one element is `x`. The other element (say `y`) must lie in `S` (since it must be an ancestor of `x`), and it must hold that `x - T <= y <= x + T`. How many such `y`'s are there? Yeah, you can just query `S` to **compute the number of elements in `S` value between `[x-T, x+T]`**. This query can be answered in O(log N) time, since the number of element in `S` never exceedes N.

More specifically, candidates of this data structure are [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), or other similar tree data structures (e.g. AVL-tree, RB-tree, Treap, etc...) supporting addition and deletion operations. Alternatively, [Fenwick Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) or [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) also can these queries in O(log N) time, too.

In summary, by maintaining all the ancestors of current visiting node, and summing up the number of pairs (including the current node) you can find the number of all similar pairs. Since we have single query for each node in the tree, the overall time complexity is **O(N log N)**.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a depth first search of the tree, using a binary indexed tree (see [Topcoder tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees#read) ) to store all the values seen in the stack.

This allows you to do a O(log(n)) query of the number of parent nodes in the required range, so the overall complexity will be O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 1):

I did it with map. You just save parent for each node and then recursively calculate similar pairs for each node.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution
{

    static Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    static int similarPairs = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int totalRows = sc.nextInt();
        int T = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalRows - 1; i++)
        {
            int data = sc.nextInt();
            int cdata = sc.nextInt();
            int currValue = cdata;

            map.put(cdata, data);

            while (map.get(cdata) != null)
            {

                int parent = map.get(cdata);

                if (Math.abs(parent - currValue) <= T)
                {
                    similarPairs += 1;
                }

                cdata = parent;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(similarPairs);
    }
}
```

Comment: although this solution works it isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, which could be implemented in low level C without the need for any list/dictionary/loopup structures such as hashtables.

1. Read the input data, storing each parsed row, and working out the maximum number of children M that a node can have
2. Allocate an array of integers of `int[] arr_of_ints = new int[n*M]`, and initialise all entries to 0.  The idea is that the node i (where 1<=i<=n) corresponds to the M integers arr_of_ints[M*(i-1)] to arr_of_ints[M*i], and the values of those entries are the children of that node
3. Run through the parsed data that was saved, and fill in arr_of_ints, working out which node is at the top
4. Allocate an array `int[] ancestors = new int[n]`, which will store the values of all the ancestors
5. Finally, starting from the top of the tree, run down through the tree with a recursive function, using the array `ancestors` so that at each node it's not necessary to retrace through the tree to calculate the number of similar nodes.  The deeper in the recursion that you are, the further along the array `ancestors` you are, but then when you reach the end of branch that position unwinds

As far as I can see, if there's enough memory for arr_of_ints[M*i], this should be as fast as it gets.

**Update**: I've coded up a version of my solution in C#, see below, and I think it's O(n log n).

```
class Solution {
    static char[] space = new char[] { ' ' };
    class FileRow {
        public readonly int parent;
        public readonly int child;
        public FileRow(string str) {
            string[] split = str.Split(space);
            parent = int.Parse(split[0]); child = int.Parse(split[1]);
        }
    }
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        List<FileRow> inputdata = new List<FileRow>();
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("inputfile.txt");
        String[] split = sr.ReadLine().Split(space);
        int n = int.Parse(split[0]), T = int.Parse(split[1]);
        int[] arr = new int[n]; // this will record the max num of children
        while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
            FileRow fr = new FileRow(sr.ReadLine());
            arr[fr.parent - 1]++;
            inputdata.Add(fr);
        }
        sr.Close();
        int M = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            M = Math.Max(M, arr[i]);
            arr[i] = 0;    // set all arr to zero, for use below in setting up tree
        }
        int[,] tree = new int[n, M];
        Boolean[] not_root_node = new bool[n];   // all entries automatically initialised to false
        foreach (FileRow fr in inputdata) {
            not_root_node[fr.child - 1] = true;  // indicate that node fr.child isn't the root node of the tree
            tree[fr.parent - 1, arr[fr.parent - 1]++] = fr.child;
        }
        int count = 0, node = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < not_root_node.Length; i++) {
            if (!not_root_node[i]) {
                count++; node = i + 1;
            }
            arr[i] = 0;    // set all arr to zero, for use below in calculating result
        }
        if (count != 1) throw new Exception("ERROR, root node for tree not unique, count="+count.ToString());
        // int node is the root of the tree
        int level = 0, result = 0;
        int[] ancestors = new int[n];
        do {
            int j = arr[node - 1];
            int nextnode = (j < M ? tree[node - 1,j] : 0);
            if (nextnode == 0) {
                level--;
                if (level >=0) node = ancestors[level];
            } else {
                ancestors[level++] = node;                
                arr[node - 1]++;
                node = nextnode;
                for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                    if (Math.Abs(ancestors[i] - node) <= T) result++;
                }
            }
        } while (level >= 0);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The 5th step (recursive query) is where it gets expensive (n can be up to 100,000). check out the accepted answer, it is way faster.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean.  Step 5 will only visit each node once, so my solution is O(n).

Comment: Your solution can theoretically not be O(n) since for each node you need at least to traverse the tree to the depth, so the best possible solution is at least O(N*logN).

Comment: Each node does only get visited once, so I still *think* you're wrong.  It wouldn't take me long to code up my idea, but I'd need a big data set to test it on.  Where can I find one?

Comment: here is the link, good luck! :)
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack/challenges/similarpair

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realise that they didn't give you large data sets to test.  Anyway, I've posted a C# version of my solution, and I still think it's O(n).

Comment: I've just realised that it is indeed O(n log n), so I've edited the answer to say so!